# Google App Script Not working, adding default value with onChange trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have this code on my google sheet app script which supposed to do a "give a condition with set default value for a cell whenever there is a new data row inside the sheet":

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {

  var row = e.range.getRow(); 
  var cellAbove = e.range.getRow()-1; 
  var upperCell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellAbove,4).getValue(); 

if (upperCell === "Chris"){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue("Genki");
    GmailApp.sendEmail("dfgdg@gmail.com", "form submit", "Message for Genki");
  } else {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue("Chris");
  GmailApp.sendEmail("ddhalim@gmail.com", "form submit", "Message for Chris");
}
}
```

I put the trigger setting **"on Change"**. The problem is, my function is not working on the trigger.
my condition are the form is working and I have a sheet where whenever someone enter a form on my site, it will add the new data on my google sheets (using another script). The new data will be the first 3 column: timestamp, nama and email. Whereas the Agent column will be filled automaticaly with my script. Although the trigger **"On change"** is not working, when i change the trigger with "on Edit" and i type a new data on any cell, the script is working. All i want to achieve is whenever a new data row is created, the "Agent" column will be filled according to the condition.

[my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eTLE.png)

Is there any solution to this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

------------------------ update:
this is my full script:

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup () {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost (e) {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
  lock.tryLock(10000)

  try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1
   

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
    

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}



function onSelectionChange(e) {

  var row = e.range.getRow(); 
  var cellAbove = e.range.getRow()-1; 
  var upperCell = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellAbove,4).getValue(); 

if (upperCell === "Chris"){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue("Genki");
    //GmailApp.sendEmail("my_email", "subject", "message");
  } else {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue("Chris");
  //GmailApp.sendEmail("another_mail", "subject", "message");
}
}
```

Comment: `onSelectionChange` is a simple trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee) So when you want to use this function as OnChange trigger, I would like to propose to rename the function name. And, about `it will add the new data on my google sheets (using another script)`, can you provide the script of `using another script`? I thought if modifying the script of `using another script` might resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response @tanaike, i have update the question with my full script. renaming the function did not solve the problem. :_(

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. In your script, only when a cell is selected, the script works. So I had just explained about the function name of `onSelectionChange`. I deeply apologize for this. About your additional script, in your goal, when the new row is added, you want to check the one above row using `upperCell === "Chris"`. Is my understanding correct? I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Do not worry Tanaike Sensei, your english is good. =)  Your understanding is correct, my script will check the above row with this upperCell === "Chris" and return the corresponding value. But the problem is, when the new data row is inserted from my form, my script is not working. The trigger used is "onChange"

Comment: Thank you for replying. Using your additional script, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? In my modification, when `doPost` is run, `newRow` is updated. So in this case, your `onSelectionChange` is not required to be used. But, if that was not useful for your situation, I apologize. As an important point, when you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a new row is added, you want to check the one above row using `upperCell === "Chris"`.

In this case, how about modifying your `doPost` function as follows?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```
var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
  return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
})

sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])
```

##### To:

```
var newRow = headers.map(function (header) {
  return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
})

var upperCell = sheet.getRange(nextRow - 1, 4).getValue();
if (upperCell === "Chris") {
  newRow[3] = "Genki";
  //GmailApp.sendEmail("my_email", "subject", "message"); // You will use this line?
} else {
  newRow[3] = "Chris";
  //GmailApp.sendEmail("another_mail", "subject", "message"); // You will use this line?
}

sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow]);
```

- In this modification, when `doPost` is run, the last row of the current sheet is checked. By this, the array of `newRow` is updated.
- And, in this case, your `onSelectionChange` is not required to be used.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- You can see the detail of this in the report of "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".
- My proposed script is a simple script. So please modify it for your actual situation.

Comment: I have tried your solution but it is still not working. Sorry. The form is still working, whenever user submit the form, the new data will be inserted in a new row, but the value for last column is still empty.

Comment: @ddhalim Thank you for replying. I think that when my proposed script is reflected in your script, the column "D" has the value. So, from `but the value for the last column is still empty.`, I'm worried about whether your modified script is correctly reflected in your Web Apps. I apologize for this. So, can you reflect the latest version of your latest script to Web Apps again? And please test it again.